# Can any sense be made of the following conjecture? For any given $x$ in $[0,1]$, "most" measure 1 subsets of $ [0,1]$ contain $ x$.

Tags: measure-theory

Can any  sense be made of the following conjecture?  For any given $x$ in $[0,1]$,  "most"  measure $1$ subsets of $[0,1]$ contain $x$.  More generally what kinds of non-trivial measures exist on sets of sets of reals?

Comment: Ridiculous that this is being voted to close. What context do people need here? This isn't an elementary homework problem.

Comment: Point process are an example, such as poisson process, or spectrum of a random (psd) matrix. The ones I've seen are almost surely locally finite, but you can easily make up some that aren't (like, fill in every other interval created by the points of the process). I guess you want some kind of natural measure. One property that I think it should have is that if you condition the subset on lying in a subinterval, the process should look like the original process (after an affine rescaling). (This is to be like the uniform measure.)

Comment: The process that picks a uniform point x and declares that the set has that restriction property (i.e. conditioning on lying in a subinterval and then rescaling doesn't change the measure), so probably you want to also require that the random subset is almost surely uncountable. I don't know if any measures satisfying both those properties exist. (P.S. The inspiration for that 'restriction property' as a way to emulate uniformity is this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204277.pdf )